# Excel: data matching between to columns, and extraction of a third value

Tags: excel

I have been messing around with a dataset that I need to clear the data.

**The challenge I am facing is:**

- I have a list of companies corresponding to some activity codes in Column C.
- A company might have various activities, and then this list of activities is repeated per each company.
- In column K, I have the activity codes with the description (note: these activities do not correspond with the rows).
- I need to match the activities in Column C with the Activities in Column K, extract the description from Column L, and then insert to the corresponding activity in column D.

I have been messing around with Vlookup but could not find a solution.

Please do kindly help me if you might have a proposal on how to do the above mentioned.

Comment: An image, please.

Answer (score 0):

Insert this in `D2`:
`=VLOOKUP(C2,K:L,2,FALSE)`
and drag it down to the rest of column `D`